# change icon for wine application

Tags: wine, icons

Is there a way to change the icon that a wine application (in this instance, spotify) uses. I can change the menu and dock icons easily enough, the one i want to change is the one that appears when the application runs, and appears in the notification area.

Whenever i run it at the minute, it reverts back to its old, low res icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can change it, spotify really tries hard to be the less themeable as possible, something about brand management.

If you are a paying member, you can use the linux version. It has a decent resolution, grey notification icon that fits nicely with Ubuntu default themes. But they try to manage their own window, it has it's own title bar, buttons on the right and it doesn't bubble when you move it. You can force compiz to manage it, but then you have two sets of close, minimize and maximize buttons.